# Link with parameters

Tags: php, model-view-controller, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am new in prestashop (version 1.6) and I have some problem about a link.
I want to add another login link with extra parameters so that I can hide registration part from connexion page.
So in nav.tpl, I added extra parameters :

`$link->getPageLink('my-account', true, NULL, ['params' => 'myTest'])|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}`

When  I click on that link, It completely disappear and in AuthController (initContent) `Tools:getValue('params')` returns null. I don't know how to figure it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should work with Smarty.

The parameter you should pass the file AuthController in function initContent.

Edit this:

```
$this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                'inOrderProcess' => true,
                'PS_GUEST_CHECKOUT_ENABLED' => Configuration::get('PS_GUEST_CHECKOUT_ENABLED'),
                'PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE' => Configuration::get('PS_REGISTRATION_PROCESS_TYPE'),
                'sl_country' => (int)$this->id_country,
                'countries' => $countries
            ));
```

Alternative method
In the same function you can do another change

Of prestashop you can use the GET and POST using the function:

```
$param = (int) (Tools::getValue ('myTest'));
```

Comment: Using getValue() in initContent returns null I also noticed that after clicking on link (that contains parameters), the link is redefined as my-account without the parameters

Answer (score 0):

The Array that you have passed to getPageLink function seems wrong, please try the following:

```
{$params = ['params' => 'myTest']}
$link->getPageLink('my-account', true, NULL, $params)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because when a FrontController is protected (such as MyAccountController) the user is redirected to the login page and the query params are lost. To fix it, change /classes/controller/FrontController.php:

```
Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication'.($this->authRedirection ? '&back='.$this->authRedirection : ''));
```

to:

```
Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=authentication'.($this->authRedirection ? '&back='.$this->authRedirection.'&'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : ''));
```

That should preserve the additional query params on the login page.